# How to add a custom image (<xh:img>) to PDF

Tags: pdf, orbeon

We would like to add an image to our PDF in Orbeon. We explorered different tags and came up with  tag. This worked the way we wanted but this tag keeps the PDF from building. We don't get any (visible) errors but a time-out occurs after couple of seconds.

To cross check: PDF build fine without the xh:img tag.

I was wondering what other options do we have. I thought about a PDF template but we would like to give the form author the option to choose his/hers own jpg from a web resource.

This is on 43PE.

Comment: What error are you getting, say in `orbeon.log`, if any? How can we reproduce this? Could you update your question with those pieces of information?

Comment: Sorry. Tried it again in another form and it worked. Don't know what we did wrong.

Comment: Ok, great, and thanks for the update, and for also posting an update as an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

User error yet we didn't change much after all.